# Edge Extension browser.runtime.sendmessage()

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Trying to convert an extension from chrome to edge and I'm having an issue with browser.runtime.sendmessage() with a listener.  To simplify things, I created a simple hello world extension.  This new extension works in chrome but not edge.   Anybody know what I need to change?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "author" : "Sandbox",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": [ "jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "content_script.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*" ]
  } ],
  "permissions": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage" ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
      "background.js"
    ], 
    "persistent": true 
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request.greeting);
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

**content_scripts.js**

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    if (response != undefined) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure but I ran into this issue and looked like Edge requires to refresh the page in order to send a message.

Comment: When in chrome, you should use `chrome.*` api while in Edge, you should use `browser.*` api.

Comment: As far as I can tell it doesn't matter if I use browser or chrome in edge or chrome, but I didn't realize I was mix and matching. I will make them all the same when I get back to work Monday

Comment: When I made them both "Browser" it works.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for Edge is found here: [Edge Supported APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis)

In the note section:

```
For Microsoft Edge, all extension APIs are under the browser namespace, 
e.g. browser.browserAction.disable().
Microsoft Edge extension APIs use callbacks, not promises.
```

Use browser.runtime.sendMessage() instead of chrome.runtime.sendMessage().

Comment: Almost 3 years after I figured that out, but thank you for taking the time to answer.